# @elastic/apm-rum-angular Integration with Angular 16 Not Working

Tags: angular, elastic-apm, angular16

I updated angular to v16 and i get the following error:

Error: src/app/app.module.ts:157:5 - error NG6002: 'ApmModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.

157     ApmModule,
~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@elastic/apm-rum-angular/apm.module.d.ts:28:22
28 export declare class ApmModule {
~~~~~~~~~
This likely means that the library (@elastic/apm-rum-angular) which declares ApmModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version
of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

It worked with v15 and i have the latest version of apm.
Does anyone has a solution for this?

Tried to use different versions of apm

Comment: It's a known error, there is a [Pull Request](https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-rum-js/pull/1380) open that should solve it. But as of now the lib does not support Ivy. Hopefully soon there will be a new version out with the fix.